# How to disable/turn off Automatic URL alias

Tags: 6, uri, path-aliases

Could anyone suggest how to disable/turn off automatic URL aliases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automatic URL aliasing? It will be the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module doing that. You can disable it, but you will need to delete your current aliases as well, which the Pathauto module provides an interface for if you check its settings.